# Unable connect to SQL Server from Winforms application after deploy

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

My application is working in debug mode or from Visual Studio. But after deployment / publish, we are not able to connect to the database from setting file connection string.

```
 BILLING_SYSTEM.Settings setting = new BILLING_SYSTEM.Settings();
```

We are using

```
string connectionString = setting.ConnectionString_Web.ToString()
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Connection String is:

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=<databaseName>;Integrated Security=True
```

Its working on local. But after deploy on another machine not able to connect database.

Is there any method in set wizard which resolve my problem?

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what connection string are you using? What exception do you get? How do you know it is not working. In order for us the help you you need to provide all the details. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That code snippet (and your description) is insufficient for anyone to figure out what you are trying to do... Just saying.

Comment: IS TCP/IP sockets enabled on the deployment machine?
Can you telnet to localhost:1433 (uou'll get a plank screen as ansver)

Comment: `Data Source=.` means the local database server. So application tries to connect to local database server that's why it works on local but not from another machine. You need to get the correct database server name and instance name of the server which you want to connect to and put them in the connection string. And also need to make sure that TCP port 1433 is opened for inboud connections in firewall settings so that another machine can connect to the database.

Comment: You are right. Its working on local but I have same database on my another machine also. If the case . finds local then it might work.

Comment: Is there any method in set wizard which resolve my problem?

Comment: Thanks. Problem is solved with connection string data source name. I have used only (.) previously. But in my case it needs (.\SQLEXPRESS).